# Thread execution of value emitting code and value receiving code in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java3

I have following code:

```
private static void log(Object msg) {
        System.out.println(
                Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                        ": " + msg);
}

Observable<Integer> naturalNumbers = Observable.create(emitter -> {
            log("Invoked"); // on main thread
            Runnable r = () -> {
                log("Invoked on another thread");
                int i = 0;
                while(!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                    log("Emitting "+ i);
                    emitter.onNext(i);
                    i += 1;
                }
            };
            new Thread(r).start();
        });
Disposable disposable = naturalNumbers.subscribe(i -> log("Received "+i));
```

So here we have 2 important lambda expressions. First is the one we pass to Observable.create, second is the callback one we pass to Observable.subscribe(). In first lambda, we create a new thread and then emit values on that thread. In second lambda, we have the code to receive those values emitted in first lambda code. I observe that both code are executed on same thread.

```
Thread-0: Invoked on another thread
Thread-0: Emitting 0
Thread-0: Received 0
Thread-0: Emitting 1
Thread-0: Received 1
Thread-0: Emitting 2
Thread-0: Received 2
```

Why is it so? Does RxJava by default run code emitting values(observable) and the code receiving values(observer) on same thread?

Comment: Yes, RxJava is synchronous by default. You need operators such as `observeOn` to change where the observation of events takes place. Such operators add overhead and many operations don't need to change threads in the first place. For the rest, the 'target' thread has to be specified in the form of a `Scheduler`.

Comment: This word 'synchronous' is really overloaded in programming community, and I see several ways people defining it. I guess what you mean here is that both emission of data and consumption of data happens from same thread. If that is the case, I have a question. If you see in output, there is interleaving of emission code and receiver code. How is that possible if both are on same thread?

Comment: Why would they be on different threads? Their `log` methods are called within the same threading context. These are regular Java method invocations which have ordering and happen one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, what happens, if you use a `Thread` to execute a runnable:

### Test

```
@Test
  void threadTest() throws Exception {
    log("main");
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    new Thread(
            () -> {
              log("thread");
              countDownLatch.countDown();
            })
        .start();

    countDownLatch.await();
  }
```

### Output

```
main: main
Thread-0: thread
```

It seems, that the main entry point is called from `main` thread and the newly created `Thread` is called `Thread-0`.

> Why is it so? Does RxJava by default run code emitting values(observable) and the code receiving values(observer) on same thread?

By default `RxJava` is single-threaded. Therefore the the producer, if not definied differently by `observeOn`, `subscribeOn` or different threading layout, will emit values on the `consumer` (subsriber)-thread. This is because `RxJava` runs everything on the subscribing stack by default.

### Example 2

```
@Test
  void fdskfkjsj() throws Exception {
      log("main");

      Observable<Integer> naturalNumbers =
        Observable.create(
            emitter -> {
              log("Invoked"); // on main thread
              Runnable r =
                  () -> {
                    log("Invoked on another thread");
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                      log("Emitting " + i);
                      emitter.onNext(i);
                      i += 1;
                    }
                  };
              new Thread(r).start();
            });
    Disposable disposable = naturalNumbers.subscribe(i -> log("Received " + i));

    Thread.sleep(100);
  }
```

### Output2

```
main: main
main: Invoked
Thread-0: Invoked on another thread
Thread-0: Emitting 0
Thread-0: Received 0
Thread-0: Emitting 1
```

In your example it is apparent, that the main method is called from the main thread. Furthermore the `subscribeActual` call is also run on the calling-thread (`main`). But the `Observable#create` lambda calls `onNext` from the newly created thread `Thread-0`. The value is pushed to the subscriber from the calling thread. In this case, the calling thread is `Thread-0`, because it calls `onNext` on the downstream subscriber.

### How to separate producer from consumer?

Use `observeOn`/ `subscribeOn` operators in order to handle concurrency in `RxJava`.

### Should I use low-level Thread constructs ẁith RxJava?

No you should not use `new Thread` in order to seperate the producer from the consumer. It is quite easy to break the contract, that `onNext` can not be called concurrently (interleaving) and therefore breaking the contract. This is why `RxJava` provides a construct called `Scheduler` with `Worker`s in order to mitigate such mistakes.

Note:
I think this article describes it quite well: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html . Please note this is Rx.NET, but the principle is quite the same. If you want to read about concurrency with `RxJava` you could also look into Davids Blog (https://akarnokd.blogspot.com/2015/05/schedulers-part-1.html) or read this Book (Reactive Programming with RxJava https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/reactive-programming-with/9781491931646/)